# Moving partitions to the root partition

Tags: linux, partition, hard-drive

I am currently stuck with a restrictive partitioning scheme that makes my partitions fill up. It looks like this:

```
/dev/sda7             870G  315G  511G  39% /
/dev/sda6             2.0G  271M  1.6G  15% /tmp
/dev/sda3              15G   13G  1.5G  90% /usr
/dev/sda2              15G  8.6G  5.0G  64% /var
/dev/sda1              99M   36M   58M  39% /boot
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

I want to move the data in `/usr` (and `/var` as well, probably) to the root partition. I don't really care about the partitions themself, so a merge is not required.

What would be the best approach in doing this? Currently, my plan is this:

```
cp -R /usr /newusr
umount /usr
mv /newusr /usr
```

Could it really be this simple, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. Create a directory on the root partition, copy your data there, unmount the `usr` partition and move your new directory to `usr`. Don't forget to edit your `/etc/fstab` afterwards.

Comment: It is not enough, cp -R doesn't copies hard links, symlinks, sockets, devices, suidbits and acls correctly. He needs cp -vfa

Comment: `cp -av` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you should always check, if you have enough free space. This time, you have.
2. About the copy:

Not so simple. There special files, whose special attributes isn't copied always correctly. Instead of `cp -R`, use

```
cp -vfa /usr /newusr
```

If you like to see what is currently being done, this can be reached with the "-v" flag.

3. Don't forget to edit `/etc/fstab` to the changes.
4. WARNING: After a repartitioning, the kernel can't always to re-read your new partition table, and thus it is possible, that it will use further your old! It is very dangerous! The version of the kernel about the current partition table can be found in `/proc/partitions`, and the partition table on disk can be read with an `fdisk -l /dev/sda`. If there is a mismatch about the partition which you like to change currently, best thing to reboot.

Comment: Where exactly do you see anything about repartitioning in the question?

Comment: @etagenklo Because the next rational step after a such operation is a complex repartitioning/resizing, although I admit it wasn't mentioned in the question directly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this it would be necessary to do it on single user mode or using a LiveCD, that's what you'll find on internet.

Furthermore, it's possible to perform this at runtime (a little bit risky, of course) but I think this way will only work for /var and not for **/usr**, some runtime libs depend on this folder. You can try on a test machine previously if it do works.

First at all you **must** check that any process/services is using/writing to the directory you want to move.

```
lsof | grep -E '/usr|/var'
```

Generally /var is still in use for pid and sock files, **/usr** as well as any lib will need it.

So, stop/kill services and processes that appear.

```
COMMAND    PID  TID        USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE   SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
cupsd      723             root    5u      REG                8,1          0    8651393 /var/log/cups/error_log
cupsd      723             root    6u      REG                8,1          0    8651908 /var/log/cups/page_log
cupsd      723             root   12u     unix 0xffff88020d97d780        0t0       9958 /var/run/cups/cups.sock
```

In this short example, cups daemon is running and using those directories. If stop them, they will not appear on lsof output.

After that, you need a copy of your current data, I'll suggest using rsync instead of cp (in order to preserve everything, permissions, symlinks, etc.)

```
mkdir /mnt/var
mkdir /mnt/usr
```

Do your backup

```
rsync -avz /var/* /mnt/var
rsync -avz /usr/* /mnt/usr
```

Unmount folders

```
umount /var
umount /usr
```

Restore data

```
rsync -avz /mnt/var/* /var
rsync -avz /mnt/usr/* /usr
```

Edit your **/etc/fstab** file and comment/delete the entries where **/var** and **/usr** where supposed to be mounted.

Then you can start all services you stopped or restart your machine. If for **/usr** doesn't work, you can't stop a daemon (maybe you can't kill it cause depends on init pid) the only way will be using a LiveCD.

Though you didn't mention which type of machine is (your PC, office machine, a server, etc) it will depend on this to do perform the formal way possible.